# how to convert from cv::Mat to CvArr?

Tags: c++, opencv

i have passed a lot of time searching on how to convert from cv::Mat or CvMat to CvArr but with no gain ,please help me in that,thanks.

Comment: CvArr is a function parameter "method" to pass multiple types of image data. It's not a type but a metatype. So, whatever you do, it's cvMat what you need.

Answer (score 5):

```
Mat img = imread("C:\MyPic.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
IplImage tmp=img;
cvErode(&tmp, &tmp, 0, 2);
Mat laser=&tmp;
    imshow("Eroded",laser);
```

I converted `cv::Mat` to `CvArr` by this way. Instead of using `tmp` directly use `&tmp`.

Answer (score 4):

When I need to do that I just use :

```
IplImage tmp = image;
```

With image a Mat variable.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, CvMat IS a CvArr so you can just cast it into a CvArr, and the first bytes of the now CvArr tell the function that it is actually a CvMat:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#cvarr

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to convert it? sometimes there is equivalent function that use what you have. For example `cvMorphologyEx` is using `CvArr` but `morphologyEx` is using `cv::Mat`.

Answer (score -1):

convert first the image using the following:

```
IplImage* oldstyleimg = &matimg.operator IplImage()
```

I don t remember if it only create the header for the image or it makes a copy